How should a custom django server error view be tested?
In the Django documentation they provide the following example for testing custom error views.
Given the following example how would you go about testing a custom server_error view? I'm able to trigger the custom view by raising ImproperlyConfigured however my test result is "E", error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured.
# views.py

from django.views import defaults

def custom_server_error_view(request):
    template_name = 'wholesale/500.html'
    print('this is running')
    return defaults.server_error(
        request,
        template_name=template_name,
    )

# tests.py

from django.core import exceptions
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from . import views


def raises500(request):
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured


urlpatterns = [
    path('500/', raises500),
]
handler500 = views.custom_server_error_view


@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF=__name__)
class CustomErrorViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_custom_server_error_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('/500/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'wholesale/500.html')



I found the answer in the documentation under making requests.

The raise_request_exception argument allows controlling whether or not exceptions raised during the request should also be raised in the test. Defaults to True.

My solution is to override this and set it to False.
def test_custom_server_error_view(self):
    server_error_client = Client(raise_request_exception=False)
    response = server_error_client.get('/500/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'wholesale/500.html')

A similar setting can be used to test CSRF failure.
def test_custom_csrf_failure_view(self):
    csrf_client = Client(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
    response = csrf_client.post('/403_csrf/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'wholesale/403_csrf.html')

